# How to enable spellcheck in vim on git-commit

Tags: git, vim

I am trying to enable the spell in Vim in case of editing the git commit message. 
The filename is fixed, so autocmd won't help.
I've put a modeline in the initial message, but the `ftpplugin/gitcommit.vim` disables the modeline.

What is the way to have custom vim settings for git-commit case?

Comment: The filename is fixed but the file is only used for commit messages, so autocmd should help, no?

Comment: As @phd says, if the filename is fixed, why not use `autocmd` for the file? `autocmd BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG set spell` should work. (Note the name `COMMIT_EDITMSG` is specified in `man git-commit`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

git commit msg has filetype `gitcommit`. You can add autocmd on that filetype, for example:

```
autocmd FileType gitcommit setlocal spell
```

All commit message in your vim should have  spell check activated.

Comment: Why not simply `set spell` rather than `let &spell = 1` ?

Comment: @filbranden set spell is better. I copied and modified that line from my vimrc... my line has something like `let x=y...` I should modify more

Comment: `setlocal`, please! And maybe also mention `after/ftplugin` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override ftplugins with the `after/ftplugin` directory, so I put

```
setlocal spell
```

in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`. Don’t forget to read `:help b:undo_ftplugin`.