# What will be the best .vimrc settings for working with kubernetes

Tags: vim, kubernetes

In my work I have to copy and paste sample manifest snippet from kubernetes documentation site. After copying many a time I have to correct indent and change some section of the copied content. Many a time challenges comes from the structure of the yaml file, specifically space characters and tab characters. Currently I am using the following setting

```
set number relativenumber
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
```

Is there any more setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things.

1. If you are pasting, make sure you do with `paste` set. It’s a used as a temporary setting for letting the text be put without changes. You can use `pastetoggle` for this, and tpope’s unimpaired has useful (relevant) mappings.
2. Don’t sent filetype-specific things in your vimrc. Just, don’t. See, e.g., [this QA](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22256), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57692489/4400820), or [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18493) (I have more, just ask). Instead, use a filetype-plugin. If kubernetes are all detected as yaml, you would want to use `setlocal` &co. inside `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/yaml.vim`. If they are not given a filetype, you may need to create a filetype-detection script (Google and the Vim help are quite good resources for this).
3. It’s recommended not to adjust `tabstop`, since you can’t control how wide a tab is on every display (you can always control spaces, though ;)).

Comment: Hi Ben,Thanks for the comment. I have been able to implement 1, 2. I specifically liked 2, but getting trouble to understand point 3. Can you please explain?

Comment: @ArijitMazumdar sure; for 3, i would leave tabstop where it is (default is 8). Not every display uses the same width of tabs, though, so if you need to align things, use spaces. softtabstop, shiftwidth, and expandtab help with this, as you already know. So i would just remove the tabstop line.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
 echo "set ts=2 sw=2" > ~/.vimrc
```